# Is it possible to manage multiple sessions with tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE 4 for my project and I'm trying use it for editing multiple files in the same time. I'm using setContent when I'm loading files. But I want each file to have it's own undo history.

I'm not sure if I'm able to explain. Let's say I have 3 files

```
a.html
b.html
c.html
```

I'm loading each files content when user click on their name using setContent to TinyMCE. But I want them to jump back and forward in between files while each one having it's own undo history. I also want it to remember where was selected and where was the keyboard pointer last time.

Thank you.

Comment: Each editor instance should have its own undo history in the TinyMCE object. Can I see a fiddle of what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to start seperate tinymce editors. And after showing and hiding active one using

```
tinymce.get(inactiveid).hide();
tinymce.get(activeid).show();
```